# Right to Left(rtl) english words display in html

Tags: css, right-to-left

Problem is this,

```
<p>Hi world</p>
```

LTR:

```
Hi world
```

RTL:

```
world Hi
```

I am not able get this RTL display is not using css.

I tried these css properties now.

```
direction: rtl;
unicode-bidi: embed || normal; //same effect, nothing changes.
unicode-bidi: bidi-override; //each letter comes from r-t-l. Like: dlrow iH
text-align: right;
```

Is there anyway to get the text to `world Hi` form using css.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it’s not possible, and directionality is not meant to be used for operations like this.

The `direction` property, as well as its HTML counterpart the `dir` attribute, sets the directionality of directionally neutral text. It does not affect strings that have strong inherent directionality, even if neutral characters like spaces intervene. The value `bidi-override` means what it says, it simply forces a single writing direction.

You would need to work on the words too, and since CSS has no pseudoelements that could be used here, you would need to use real elements, markup like

```
<p><span class=w>Hi</span> <span class=w>world</span></p>
```

Then you can use different directionality settings for entire element and the individual words:

```
span { unicode-bidi: embed;}
p { unicode-bidi: bidi-override; direction: rtl;  text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that the reading direction was set in the html opening tag, like so:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think with "rtl" you will get an output like: "dlrow iH"

As you can't detect separate words in CSS, I would recommend to use JavaScript for this problem:

```
var string = "Hi world";
var array = string.split(" ");
var reversed = array.reverse();
reversed
-> ["world", "Hi"]
```